TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function (in react-vite app using auth0-lock)
Issue: 
I am trying to build an app using React-vite and is using auth0-lock for doing auth0 authentication. But I'm encountering with this error. I found it to be some kind of export error when I googled.
Stack: React - vite - Javascript - Tailwind
Full Error:
auth0-lock.js?t=1713560656630&v=6df03345:34367 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at _inherits (auth0-lock.js?t=1713560656630&v=6df03345:34367:15)
    at auth0-lock.js?t=1713560656630&v=6df03345:34431:7
    at node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/core.js (auth0-lock.js?t=1713560656630&v=6df03345:34641:6)
    at __require (chunk-B2BDBFHY.js?v=70481260:9:50)
    at node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/lock.js (auth0-lock.js?t=1713560656630&v=6df03345:34681:41)
    at __require (chunk-B2BDBFHY.js?v=70481260:9:50)
    at node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/index.js (auth0-lock.js?t=1713560656630&v=6df03345:37581:40)
    at __require (chunk-B2BDBFHY.js?v=70481260:9:50)
    at auth0-lock.js?t=1713560656630&v=6df03345:37591:16

My code:
import { Auth0LockPasswordless } from "auth0-lock";

const Preview = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between border-b-[2px] border-[#f0f0f0] p-6">
      <h1 className="text-black text-xl font-semibold">Preview</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const lock = new Auth0LockPasswordless("clientId", "domain");
          lock.show();
        }}
        className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-1 rounded"
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Preview;

What I've tried: 

I tried adding the following to vite.config.js to fix if it was an export issue.

resolve: {
    alias: {
       'auth0-lock': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/auth0-lock/lib/index.js')
    },
  },


I tried using the vite-plugin-commonjs and that also doesn't seem to work

// vite.config.js
import commonjs from "vite-plugin-commonjs";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [commonjs()],

